# Undefined mixin 'global-reset' when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, compass-geolocation

Any ideas why does this happen when deploying to Heroku:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Undefined mixin 'global-reset'.
       (in /tmp/build_b4afrg7i0afu/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.css.scss)

       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
```

I have an scss file with:

```
@import "compass/reset";
```

but why is it not finding it when compiling assets? Is there a way to just not compile them? It works fine at runtime and this step generates an exception that gets into airbrake and it's a pain.

**Update**: I run rake assets:precompile locally and I found the error seems to be generated by activeadmin:

```
$ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Undefined mixin 'global-reset'.
  (in /Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.css.scss)
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.css.scss:4:in `global-reset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/activeadmin-0.4.0/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/_base.css.scss:4
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:170:in `visit_mixin'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:27:in `block in visit_children'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:39:in `with_environment'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:26:in `visit_children'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:47:in `visit_root'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:18:in `visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:300:in `_render'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/engine.rb:247:in `render'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sass-rails-3.1.5/lib/sass/rails/template_handlers.rb:95:in `evaluate'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in `render'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:175:in `block in evaluate'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:172:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:172:in `evaluate'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:171:in `build_dependency_context_and_body'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:135:in `dependency_context'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:194:in `build_dependencies_paths_and_assets'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:141:in `dependency_paths'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:61:in `mtime'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:58:in `block in encode_with'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:57:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/asset.rb:57:in `encode_with'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:43:in `encode_with'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:52:in `cache_asset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:67:in `block in build_asset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:76:in `memoize'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:65:in `build_asset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/trail.rb:102:in `find_asset_in_path'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:101:in `find_asset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:48:in `find_asset'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:20:in `block in compile'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:151:in `block in each_logical_path'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in each_file'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:129:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:129:in `each_entry'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:137:in `block in each_file'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:136:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:136:in `each_file'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/sprockets-2.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:149:in `each_logical_path'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:52:in `internal_precompile'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/pupeno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@watu/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
```

[I reported this issue in case it's a bug](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/985).

Comment: One solution is to use `rake assets:precompile` before pushing to heroku. Had the same problem once, had to precompile the assets.

Comment: @Terw I don't like having to commit a lot of generated files that rails can regenerate just fine at any point. It adds a lot of noise to the version control repo (I did it for a while when there was no other way, now I stopped).

Comment: Does it work if you run `heroku run rake assets:precompile` when it's deployed?

Comment: @NeilMiddleton I haven't tried, but it doesn't even work locally, so there we go. I updated the answer to include the error.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you did all of the following:

In config/application.rb, ensure you have the line:

`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`

If you're loading scss files other than application.css, make sure they're included in the assets pipeline. You'll need a line line the following at the top of the file:

`/*= require_self */`

In addition to #2, In config/environments/production.rb, add those files to the assets list. For instance, if your file is `my.scss`, you need a line like:

`config.assets.precompile += %w( my.css )`

Finally, there's a great guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html